# Avada Theme: Expand/Collapse Tabs or Toggles with Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, themes, toggle

Is there any way to expand and collapse tabs or toggles via a button or a link? If say, I have a button that is positioned away from the Toggle section, and I want to use it to trigger the expanding and collapsing of the Toggle section, is this possible to do with anchors or some other way?

Comment: Very likely this is possible, but be aware SO is not a code writing service. Please read [ask] and try your best to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Well, I wasn't asking someone to write a code, but more of, if anybody knows if Avada has some built-in functionality to easily achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while but I hope this will help someone.

I looked around quite a bit to find some Avada reference for a js api that would allow me to toggle a tab or collapse an accordion but I found nothing...

So I falled back to the easiest, but not the cleanest, solution I had.

Toggle with jQuery!

```
jQuery('[href="#tab-d1419ff5c152c6084b6"]').first().click();
```

Just inspect your tab or accordion and grab the content of `href`, then tell jQuery to find and click the element.

Note that in my code I use `.first()` this is because there were more than one elements in the dom with the same `href` and it caused some flicker on the screen.